# Rate of recoveries in SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

The [SIR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology) used to study the dynamics 
of epidemics is given be the differential equations
\begin{align*}
\dot S(t) &= -\beta\,I(t)\,S(t) \\ 
\dot I(t) &= \beta\,I(t)\,S(t) - \gamma\,I(t) \\ 
\dot R(t) &= \gamma\,I(t)
\end{align*}
I don't understand the rationale for the last equation. Assuming that the infection lasts for a (given) time $t^*$, the Ansatz
$$
\dot R(t) = \beta\,I(t-t^*)\,S(t-t^*)
$$ 
(and correspondingly
$
\dot I(t) = \beta\,I(t)\,S(t) - \beta\,I(t-t^*)\,S(t-t^*)
$) appears to be more natural, since it ensures
$R(t) \approx I(t-t^*)$ at the *start* of an epidemic.
I.e. the number of people recovering at time $t$ 
corresponds to the number of people having contracted 
the infection at time $t-t^*$. What am I missing?

Comment: For one it gives a system of delay-differential equations. The SIR model models the recovery time as a distribution allowing for different individuals to recover at different rates. And why the $S(t-t^*)$ term? Why does the size susceptible population affect the recovery of infected people? If everyone has the disease people can still recover even though $S=0$.

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment. The term involving the $S(t-t^*)$ expression reflects the simple idea that all people *newly* infected at $t$ (viz. $\beta\,I(t)\,S(t)$) will recover at $t+t^*$. I agree that the delay-differential equation is awkward from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: $S(t-t^*)$ has no connection to number of newly infected people. If you want everyone to have the disease for exactly $t^*$ days, then write $R(t)=I(t-t^*)$, no differential equation necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple chemical model applied to population dynamics. 
$$
S+I\xrightarrow{β}2I
\\
I\xrightarrow{γ}R
$$
It has two reactions, whenever $S$ and $I$ meet, new $I$ is produced by conversion from $S$ at rate $β$. I spontaneously converts to $R$ at rate $γ$.

As said, this is a very simple model to demonstrate some principles. More involved models will have more classes. By passing through different classes (one could for instance divide $I$ into $E=$ "exposed" and different stages of infection and healing) you also get some delay effect.